# Clang doesn't see module interface in my CMake project

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, c++20, c++-modules

I have a small project which I've refactored into C++ modules. Below is **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(myengine LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_SCAN_FOR_MODULES ON)
set(PREBUILT_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/engine/modules)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)

if(APPLE)
    add_subdirectory("libs/metal-impl")
endif()

set(ROOT_DIST_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dist)

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    set(DIST_DIR ${ROOT_DIST_DIR}/debug)
else()
    set(DIST_DIR ${ROOT_DIST_DIR}/release)
endif()

file(GLOB_RECURSE MDLS *.ixx)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRCS *.cxx)

# This is the "object library" target: compiles the sources only once
add_library(objlibmyengine OBJECT)

target_sources(objlibmyengine PUBLIC FILE_SET CXX_MODULES FILES ${MDLS} ${SRCS})

# Shared libraries need PIC
set_property(TARGET objlibmyengine PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE 1)

# Shared and static libraries built from the same object files
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlibmyengine>)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}static STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlibmyengine>)

if (APPLE)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${DIST_DIR}/lib/macos/
)

endif(APPLE)

include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/engine/src)

if (VULKAN_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Found Vulkan. Including and linking...")
    target_link_libraries(objlibmyengine Vulkan::Vulkan)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Vulkan::Vulkan)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}static Vulkan::Vulkan)
endif(VULKAN_FOUND)

if(APPLE)
    message(STATUS "Found Metal. Including and linking...")
    target_link_libraries(objlibmyengine metalimpl)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} metalimpl)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}static metalimpl)
endif()
```

What's the hell? Well... Before I had a typical headers+sources C++ project that generated shared and static libraries of my engine (static library for visual engine editor and shared library for the target game compilation). Ok, but why there is an object library? Not to compile sources twice (I didn't find a better solution).

It worked with headers and sources, now I need to achieve a something similar with modules.

Ok, let's dig into the problem... But firstly, I use **Clang v16** on **macOS v14 (aarch64)** and **CMake v3.28.3**, so it 100% supports C++ modules.

When I try to build the engine it fails with errors:

```
[main] Building folder: my 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /opt/homebrew/bin/cmake --build /Users/denis/Projects/b3/build --config Debug --target all --
[build] [2/11   9% :: 0.043] Scanning /Projects/my/engine/src/my.ixx for CXX dependencies
[build] [2/11  18% :: 0.043] Scanning /Projects/my/engine/src/my.platform.ixx for CXX dependencies
[build] [3/11  27% :: 0.053] Generating CXX dyndep file engine/CMakeFiles/objlibmyengine.dir/CXX.dd
[build] FAILED: engine/CMakeFiles/objlibmyengine.dir/CXX.dd /Projects/my/build/engine/CMakeFiles/objlibmyengine.dir/CXXModules.json engine/CMakeFiles/objlibmyengine.dir/src/my.ixx.o.modmap engine/CMakeFiles/objlibmyengine.dir/src/my.platform.core.ixx.o.modmap engine/CMakeFiles/objlibmyengine.dir/src/my.platform.darwin.ixx.o.modmap engine/CMakeFiles/objlibmyengine.dir/src/my.platform.ixx.o.modmap engine/CMakeFiles/objlibmyengine.dir/src/my.platform.core.cxx.o.modmap engine/CMakeFiles/objlibmyengine.dir/src/my.platform.darwin.cxx.o.modmap 
[build] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.28.3/bin/cmake -E cmake_ninja_dyndep --tdi=engine/CMakeFiles/objlibmyengine.dir/CXXDependInfo.json --lang=CXX --modmapfmt=clang --dd=engine/CMakeFiles/objlibmyengine.dir/CXX.dd @engine/CMakeFiles/objlibmyengine.dir/CXX.dd.rsp
[build] CMake Error: Output engine/CMakeFiles/objlibmyengine.dir/src/my.platform.core.cxx.o is of type `CXX_MODULES` but does not provide a module interface unit or partition
[build] CMake Error: Output engine/CMakeFiles/objlibmyengine.dir/src/my.platform.darwin.cxx.o is of type `CXX_MODULES` but does not provide a module interface unit or partition
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[proc] The command: /opt/homebrew/bin/cmake --build /Projects/my/build --config Debug --target all -- exited with code: 1
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:00.066
```

And I can't get why Clang does't see module interfaces. Example of problematic module is below:

**my.platform.core.ixx:**

```
export module my.platform.core;

#include <string>

export namespace my 
{

enum class EWindowMode {
    DEFAULT     = 0,
    CUSTOM      = 1,
    MINIMIZED   = 2,
    MAXIMIZED   = 3,
    FULLSCREEN  = 4,
};

struct Rect 
{
    int x;
    int y;
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;

    Rect(int x, int y, unsigned int width, unsigned int height);
};

struct WindowOptions {
    std::string title;
    EWindowMode mode = EWindowMode::DEFAULT;
    bool resizable = true;
    bool closable = true;
    bool minimizable = true;
    bool borderless = false;

    WindowOptions(std::string title);
};

class BaseApp
{
    public:
        BaseApp(std::string name);
        virtual ~BaseApp() {}

        virtual int run() = 0;

        void windowOption(WindowOptions options);

    protected:
        std::string name;
        WindowOptions window_options;
};

}
```

**my.platform.core.cxx:**

```
module;

module my.platform.core;

using namespace my;

Rect::Rect(int x, int y, unsigned int width, unsigned int height):
    x(x), y(y), width(width), height(height)
{
    
}

WindowOptions::WindowOptions(std::string title):
    title(std::move(title))
{
}

BaseApp::BaseApp(std::string name):
    name(std::move(name)),
    window_options(WindowOptions(name))
{
}

void BaseApp::windowOption(WindowOptions options) {
    this->window_options = options;
}
```

**P.S.** Modules are a new paradigm in C++ for me, so maybe I declared them wrongly.

Comment: First thought was there is an invalid file extension for Clang. I've also tried `*.cxxm` and `*.ccm`, that's not the problem.

Comment: First, you should condense things to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Modules normally work on Clang (for CMake see [here](https://www.kitware.com/import-cmake-the-experiment-is-over/) if you haven't already - my own modules are based on it and it works).

Comment: "_.ixx_" is also a MSFT-specific extension. I realize you tried changing it but update your post to reflect it. See Clang module [File name requirement](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/StandardCPlusPlusModules.html#file-name-requirement). <string> should also be #included in the [Global module fragment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules#Global_module_fragment) though that likely isn't the issue (but FYI only).

Comment: @Larry, yeah, I've visited that website before but I read another post about experimental support of C++ modules in CMake. Thank you for links and explanation!

Comment: @Larry, finally, reading that article, googling and reconfiguring my project +100500 times, I got the problem, even problems. First, the extension is really important and Clang doesn't recognise `*.ixx` as a module. And the second, I should have passed a list of `*.cxx` files as simple sources to CMake, not as modules. It's resolved my problem. Unfortunatelly, I met another problems: VS Code doesn't support C++ modules properly and Clang can't build a universal macOS library with modules, so I've decided to revert the project back to headers and sources.

Comment: @Larry, also I've known yet one thing. C++ doesn't support submodules, `module.submodule` is just a community hack, for C++ compiler it's still a simple module with name `module.submodule`. So, there is no such terms as parent and child modules, only modules and their partitions (Maybe someone misunderstood docs same like me).

Comment: Glad I could help. Can't speak to all your issues without further review (though the period in module names has no special meaning - it's for your own informal hierarchical naming only), I do agree that modules (a C++20 feature and it's now 2024), still aren't completely mainstream yet. They still have some support issues and even confirmed bugs depending on the platform (I've officially reported a couple). While I'm comfortable enough using them now for my own work, deferring them in your case may be a prudent decision (cut your losses for now if it's more trouble than it's worth).

Comment: @Larry, yes, C++ modules are a modern feature that personally I wanted to see in C++ for long time (a something like this I mean). Also I am sure next year I will try to switch again cuz it looks like IDE and compiler vendors will be production-ready with a support of C++ modules at 2025. Just for now, I don't want to struggle with IDE and compiler although even today all problems are resolvable. I want to say thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Let's resume my problems in that answer if someone will hit into same troubles:

1. Clang doesn't recognise `*.ixx` (MS variant) as a module (in case of modules the extension really plays a role, as @Larry has noticed me in comments). So, I've switched to `*.cxxm`.
2. I should have used written as below:

   ```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28) project(myengine LANGUAGES CXX)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_SCAN_FOR_MODULES ON)
    set(PREBUILT_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/engine/modules)

    find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)

    if(APPLE)
        add_subdirectory("libs/metal-impl")
    endif()

    set(ROOT_DIST_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dist)

    if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
        set(DIST_DIR ${ROOT_DIST_DIR}/debug) 
    else()
        set(DIST_DIR ${ROOT_DIST_DIR}/release) 
    endif()

    file(GLOB_RECURSE MDLS *.cxxm) file(GLOB_RECURSE SRCS *.cxx)

    # This is the "object library" target: compiles the sources only once
    add_library(objlibmyengine OBJECT)

    # FIX HERE:
    target_sources(objlibmyengine PUBLIC ${SRCS})
    target_sources(objlibmyengine PUBLIC FILE_SET CXX_MODULES FILES ${MDLS})

    # Shared libraries need PIC 
    set_property(TARGET objlibmyengine PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE 1)

    # Shared and static libraries built from the same object files
    add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlibmyengine>)
    add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}static STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlibmyengine>)

    if (APPLE)

        set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${DIST_DIR}/lib/macos/ )

    endif(APPLE)

    include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/engine/src)

    if (VULKAN_FOUND)
        message(STATUS "Found Vulkan. Including and linking...")
        target_link_libraries(objlibmyengine Vulkan::Vulkan)
        target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Vulkan::Vulkan)
        target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}static Vulkan::Vulkan)
    endif(VULKAN_FOUND)

    if(APPLE)
        message(STATUS "Found Metal. Including and linking...")
        target_link_libraries(objlibmyengine metalimpl)
        target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} metalimpl)
        target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}static metalimpl) 
    endif()
   ```

After renaming module files to `*.cxxm` and fix `CMakeLists.txt` Clang could build the library BUT I faced new problems:

1. VS Code has a bad syntax highlighting for modules, at least in my case it didn't work properly. I think it's possible to resolve but you need to dig into VS Code settings.
2. My root `CMakeLists.txt` contained `set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "arm64;x86_64")` and Clang complained that it can't build C++ modules for both architectures. And it has a workaround too, for example, I can write a shell script to run my CMake twice with different architecture flags or something else. However I give up!

**A little off topic:** All these problems and a ton of tutorials let me understand that C++ modules are still too young technology and its support is not so well still. I've decided to revert my lib back to traditional sources and headers. Maybe later I will try switching to C++ modules again when a module support will be more mature.